# Apache doesn't complete index.php for https

Tags: php, apache, https

When entering e.g. http:// mysite, the server returns https:// mysite/index.php - this is correct behavior
But when starting with https right away:
e.g. https:// mysite, the server returns only https:// mysite/ (without the index.php). 
The site loads however ok. The problem causes some incorrect behavior on the application itself. So I would like to get it including the index.php also when asking for https:// too.

This is the httpd conf file:

```
# forbid access to the entire filesystem by default
<Directory />
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory /srv/installateur/content/approot/>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
    RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|pdf|html|csv)$ /index.php [L] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    Options Indexes MultiViews SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

# use .htaccess files for overriding,
AccessFileName .htaccess
# and never show them
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

# List of resources to look for when the client requests a directory
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

---

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rewrite like that. Instead, do two virtual hosts, one for http and the other for https and use 301 redirect from http to https while keeping request params.

[Official Apache mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html) See section "Simple Redirection"